# Counting associated model rows with ecto

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I'm trying to find how many projects belong to a particular user.

I know that you can do this to get the count of a model:

```
count = User |> Repo.aggregate(:count, :id)
```

But how can I find the count of projects that belong to that user?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's one way: fetch the user, use `assoc/2` to create a query for its associations, and then count it the same way you're doing right now:

```
User |> Repo.get(123) |> assoc(:projects) |> Repo.aggregate(:count, :id)
```

Comment: That would be `Ecto.assoc/2`, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

`Projects` table belongs to `users` table, so it has the foreign key so you can do aggregate count on Project model where `project.user_id == ^user_id`

```
import Ecto.Query

def count(user_id: user_id) do
   query = from project in Project,
      where: project.user_id == ^user_id

   Repo.aggregate(query, :sum, :amount)
end
```